# POST request to Activiti REST API causes CORS issue when using Content-Type:application/json

Tags: java, tomcat7, activiti

I'm using AngularJS to consume Activit REST resources. All GET operations works as expected but, when I try to POST to /runtime/process-instances with Content-Type:application/json, it fails on the preflight. As you can see, there's no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the response header.

[image: 2015-05-08 17_29_07-activiti rest caller net]

When I change the Content-Type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8, for example, the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' comes in the response header but as we know, my POST won't work as API expects it to have a content-type:application/json

[image: 2015-05-08 17_39_01-activiti rest caller net]

How can I get around the issue?

Appreciate any input!

Comment: Post the content of your problem here. The way it is right now, this is a very poor question. That link should be a reference, not the content.

Comment: Ok, added content as suggested. But more important than that: do you have a clue? Can you help to solve the issue I'm experiencing?

Comment: Can't you just set the header by yourself?

Comment: As I stated in the issue I opened on Activiti's GitHub, I added those headers on Tomcat so that it should send it on every response -  nonetheless, the result was the same.

Answer (score 2):

Since Activiti 5.17, Activiti uses Spring Security to protect the REST-APIs. The Tomcat CORS-Filter only gets triggered if you send headers propagated in the allowed-headers field in the Tomcat CORS-Configuration. I did not succeed in triggering the CORS-filter on every request. Therefore, I did it this way:

1. Write your own CORS-Filter

   public class CorsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

   ```
       @Override
       protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
               throws ServletException, IOException {

           response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
           if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
               response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
               response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
               response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept, x-requested-with, Content-Type, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding ,Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method ,Access-Control-Request-Headers, Last-Modified, Cookie, Referer");
               response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Accept-Ranges,Content-Encoding,Content-Length,Content-Range");
               response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "100");
           }

           filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       }

   }
   ```
2. Add the filter in the Spring Configuration in the activiti-rest-webapp2:

`http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)`

and `.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()`

The options requests need to be passed without spring authentication because otherwise, the CORS preflight requests will fail.

If you do it this way, Activiti will add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin on every request you make.

Best regards
Ben