# Enable CORS in Alfresco Activiti 6 (Community)

Tags: activiti

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132867/post-request-to-activiti-rest-api-causes-cors-issue-when-using-content-typeappl) describes how to enable cors in Activiti 5.17, I tried this approach but didn't got such kind of configurations in activiti 6. It would be appreciable if anyone could provide the way to enable CORS in activiti 6 rest api.

Answer (score 1):

Lets make sure you are talking about the "Community" ReST API's because the Activiti 6 activiti-app also introduces a number of new ReST API's to support the new capabilities of the UI.

Comment: I am using activiti-rest.war came with activiti-6.0 package

Comment: The activii-rest.war that is shipped with community edition has no CORS filter, so any behavior you are seeing is coming from the container.