# CORS in Activiti 6.0

Tags: cors, activiti

How do we enable CORS in Activiti 6.0?

I've enable the CORS in activiti-app.properties as follows

```
cors.enabled=true
cors.allowed.origins=*
cors.allowed.methods=GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
cors.allowed.headers=Authorization,Content-Type,Cache-Control,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,X-CSRF-Token
cors.exposed.headers=Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials
cors.support.credentials=true
cors.preflight.maxage=10
```

But still not working? Any Idea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459396/enable-cors-in-alfresco-activiti-6-community You probably need to check your container configuration For e.g., for tomcat you can refer to https://enable-cors.org/server_tomcat.html. Or you can write your own filter and register in app like mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132867/post-request-to-activiti-rest-api-causes-cors-issue-when-using-content-typeappl

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion.
The properties you are setting are processed by the Alfresco Process Services Enterprise Edition as part of the servlet configuration (WebConfigurer.java).
The code to initialize the Cors Filter is not present in the Activiti 6 codebase (at least not that I am able to find).

Are you really using Activityi 6 or are you using Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Yes, It's Activiti 6 Community Edition. I got your point, let me enable it in Container and check if it's working, else i'll wrap Activiti REST API with my own API's, i guess this will be a easiest solution.